# angular ng if with async data?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-services, angular-ng-if

In my angular `navbar` I have a `*ngIf` for rather or not login/logout button should be showing

```
*ngIf="!authService.loggedIn()
```

it uses a service with this loggedIn function that returns true or false

```
  loggedIn() {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/users/validateToken')
      .map(res => res.json()).map(data => data.success);
  }
```

bu this is async, how I make my `ngIf` await it ? or how can I differently get the same result ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Running function in the template is a bad practice. You can have a variable which is correspond for the status of the user and store the `data.success` there. Call your async function into the `ngOnInit` and assign the result to the variable.

```
ngOnInit() {
   return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/users/validateToken')
      .map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => this.isLoggedIn = data.success);
}
```

And template would be like

```
*ngIf="isLoggedIn"
```

What about waiting for the response of the async function, you don't need to worry about it, if the result will come and be assigned to the variable - DI mechanism will detect that change and update the template

**Advice** As I guess from the `res.json()` you use not an `HttpClient`, but `Http` which is deprecated. Use `HttpClient` and `HttpClientModule`.

Comment: I tried this way, but it dosent update the loggedIn variable, it just sets it to false OnInit and never updates it. ( the navbar only getting initialized once in app.comonent.html)

Comment: Oh. We forget to subscribe to the observable so the request was not made. I have updated

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `async` pipe since if request returns a observable.

```
*ngIf="!authService.loggedIn() | async"
```

Comment: loggedIn() called infinity

Answer (score 0):

Seems like

```
*ngIf="asyncfn() | async"
```

Only leads to an infinit loop, however:

```
constructor() {
  this.result = this.asyncFn();
}
public asyncFn() { // ... }
```

template:

```
*ngIf="result | async"
```

works fine... lovely Angular... how the heck would you defer it then to only done when needed? Does Angular team hate promises?

Answer (score 0):

You can use angularJS [$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) to get Angular to recognize a function called from async.

```
$timeout(authService.loggedIn(), 50);
```

The 50 number is a little arbitrary. It's just there as part of the $timeout function.